# "Controller scaffolding" option not available, template search causes an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When going through the following:

Right click on **"Controllers"** folder => **"Add"**, there is no option to add a controller using Entity framework.

Also, when I try to search for templates online (Add => New Item => Online), it causes Visual Studio to crash.

I am using Visual studio Community 2015 (Update 3).

What seems to be the problem here?

**EDIT:** I have found out that Controller scaffolding is not available, if you create a project and do not use **Individual User Accounts authentification**

Is there any way to change authentication on an existing project?

Comment: The startup.cs is the place where the authentication can be changed. To be more specific it would be helpful to state which authentication you want to use.

Comment: Visual Studio crashing sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @rboe, I would like to use "Individual User Accounts" one. What should I change/delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooling for the ASP.NET Core framework is in Preview and several features are in an ongoing process. With some shortcomings we have to wait for Microsoft to have their homework done. Sigh...

If you want to change the authentication of an existing project to "**Individual User Accounts Authentication**" then a lot of steps have to be done in order to reproduce the boilerplate code that is generate by the project template. E.g. this includes

- Settup up Identity based on Entity Framework Core
- Definition of SQL Tables for User and Roles
- `AccountController` for Login, Passwort Reset, Email Confirmation, ...
- `ManageController` for adding logins to Facebook, Google, Microsoft Account....
- Adding all needed Packages to `project.json`
- Multiple Views for `AccountController` and `ManageController`
- Model-Classes for `AccountController` and `ManageController`
- ... (certainly I have not mentioned all items)

To make a long story short: *I suggest to create a new project based on the template an copy the logic and assets of your existing project in to this fresh project.*

Most certainly this would be easier than the other way round.